# Using the Data Access Object pattern with Retrofit

Tags: android, design-patterns, retrofit

I have an interface called, let's say, `PlacesDataSource`, for getting a list of places. It has a method called `Place getPlaces()`.

I have two classes that implement this interface, one that gets places from a local database, one goes online and makes network requests.

For the local implementation, I have:

```
List<Place> getPlaces() {
    return mDatabase.getThoseGoodPlaces();
}
```

For the online implementation, I have:

```
List<Place> getPlaces() {
    Response<List<Place>> response = myOnlineApi.getThoseGoodPlaces().execute(); // synchronous request
    return response.body()
}
```

However, this would cause `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I can change the interface method to `void getPlaces()` to use an asynchronous request. But this does not look right.

How does one usually define the interface, implement a local and an online version of it, when using the Data Access Object pattern?

Comment: I don't know how to make it look right, but accessing the db from UI thread doesn't look right either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use interface Observable> getPlaces() where Observable<> is from rxJava. Retrofit will fetch data from REST and wil pass it in .onSubscribe() method of that Obervable. For db, wrap db calls into the same method. Then you can update data from web, save it to db and return result in one chain of operators.

```
Observable.just(someQueryArgs)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(param -> webApi.doWebQuery(param))
.map(response -> saveResponseToDB(response))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(result -> updateUI(result));
```